# how to print class data members using only object name

Tags: java

```
class Jatin{
    int value = 9;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Jatin obj = new Jatin();
        String str = new String("Hello");

        System.out.println(obj);//prints unique id why
        System.out.println(str);//prints string value why
    }
}
```

How to modify this code and use obj object of class Jatin to print all its data members i.e. print out the value =9.
Whereas in String str sop print the value . Why?

Comment: You need to study about toString method in java

Comment: You need to write a toString method. Check out the links above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a getter in order to print them, or just access the specific fields directly when you print.

You could also just simply implement/override the toString method if you want a way of printing all members with one call.

For example:

```
class Jatin {
  String name = "Jatin";
  int value = 9;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\n" + " value: " + value);
  }
}
```

Or if you only need a specific value just call on the field.

```
Jatin obj = new Jatin();
System.out.println(obj.value); // will print the value
```

The reason why you only get unique hash is because you don't have `toString()`

Comment: overwrite toString would be the correct terminology

Comment: This doesn't compile as `toString()` has to return a `String`. Besides printing the value in the standard output doesn't make part of the `toString()` specification.

Comment: @Lino hey :) override you mean !

Comment: @davidxxx such a simple task. And i completly missed it. Override I meant. Yes :)

Answer (score 1):

Printing an instance of a class directly returns **className@hashcode** of that object

If you need to access the attributes of an object, you need to access them using dot operator.

In your case, `obj.value` i.e `System.out.println(obj.value);`